# Smooth scrolling jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I am making a 1page website.
When i click the navigation link "bas&harald" it should go to the second slide (to the right) smoothly.

However i cannot get this to work. I am using this script: http://www.dezinerfolio.com/wp-content/uploads/smoothscrolldemo/df_smooth_scroll.html

I implemented it in the bottom of this js file:http://www.basenharald.nl/3d/script.js
I have set the "href" element, same goes for the "a name" element.

Can anyone tell me why this is not working? Is another codesnippet conflicting with this one?
http://www.basenharald.nl/3d

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have much time to go further than this but try to remove the cufon from the menu and see if you can get it to work that way.

Comment: @Elaine Marley Tried that, but that is not working either. I think this is not caused by cufon

Comment: In your code I fail to see where it should be going when you click on the links. As far as I know even without the script it should be moving you to the correct place if the html is right (albeit without the animations).<div id="uno"><a href="#dos">Uno</a></div>
<div id="dos"><a href="#uno">Dos</a></div> Clicking uno will take you to dos and viceversa. Check the html on the script you linked as example and check that you are using ids.

Comment: I know, that worked, but when i implemented the script, it stopped working.

Comment: Don't know what else to tell you, looks like the smart3d thing you have there might be the issue? You might want to have a look at this to have a similar animation: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Comment: The easing pack is for extra animation, i do not really need extra animation. In other words, this script wont help me but thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Assuming that the code is pretty much the same, with some modifications to accomodate the solution, using the [scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin we can do:

```
$('#nav a').click(function() {
   $.scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), {duration: 500});
});
```

Which requires that all the sections have an id that appears in the nav items. duration is in milliseconds. Here's a working example of the idea: http://rolandmai.com/3d/

Comment: This is not a reall answer, i did not add the anchors because they did not work... so i deleted them. For point 3, i cannot disable the 3d part since it is the core that "layers" the images and content. So it is quite logical. about point 1, you are right... i will fix that. if the script is not good, what script would you use for this? thanks for your answer anyway

I want the anchors to link to the UL parts so it scrolls to the different UL's.

Comment: that sir, was just awesome!! have fun with the 50 rep :)

Comment: You're welcome! Btw, here's how you award the bounty: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work